# How to know if a rectangle collides against a shape such as this?

Tags: collision-detection

I have a rectangle and I want to know whether it collides against a shape such as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RMQZ.png

I've seen algorithms such as this:

```
function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
           r2.right < r1.left || 
           r2.top > r1.bottom ||
           r2.bottom < r1.top);
}
```

but that only works if both are rectangles. So how do I figure it out for a rectangle and that shape.

Answer (score 2):

I don't do this often but you could do it this way:

- Check if any of the 4 points of the rectangle is inside the polygon
- Check if any of the (10?) points of the polygon lies inside the rectangle

So this could be reduced to a "[point in polygon](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/)" problem. Again, it's likely there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at algorithms which are based on the "separating-axes-theorem". It's pretty much the standard for fast 2D collision detection, since it's (you could've guessed) very fast (doesn't involve any division or costly operations like sin/cos/sqrt/exp at all) and also works for any possible convex shape (even circles).

Here's an excellent tutorial explaining it: http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55

One thing that makes it so fast is that the algorithm has "early-out" scenarios, where you test one axis and if it doesn't return the desired result, you can exit the entire algorithm knowing that the shapes don't collide.

A nice side effect of the article is that it spits out the smallest possible displacement vector that you need to push your colliding shapes apart.